# Paypal REST API: is sale id the same as transaction id?

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm trying to determine a way to issue a refund for the user's order using the PayPal REST API. After taking a look at [this section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#refund-a-sale), I see that in the documentation on the left PayPal uses the terms "id" and "sale_id", while in the example on the right I see {transactionId}. The docs *seem* to be using the term "sale id" and "transaction id" interchangeably. Should I believe the example, and go ahead and use the transaction id I received via IPN earlier to issue a refund for the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `sale_id` is the same as `transaction id` in your PayPal account and IPN messages.